# How to calculate distance of between two rectangle corners

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I want to calculate the distance between given two DOM elements that pointed corners. I used Math.hypot function for the calculation however there is a mistake while doing it, which slightly overflows the corner instead of the exact point.

```
function getPositionAtCenter(element) {
   const {top, left, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
     x: left + width / 2,
     y: top + height / 2
   };
 }

function getDistanceBetweenElements(a, b) {
  const aPosition = getPositionAtCenter(a);
  const bPosition = getPositionAtCenter(b);

  return Math.hypot(aPosition.x - bPosition.x, aPosition.y - bPosition.y);  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract the `left` value of the second `div` from the `left` value of first `div`.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".div")
let div1Position = divs[0].getBoundingClientRect();
let div2Position = divs[1].getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(div2Position.left - div1Position.left)
```

```html
<div class="div" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:grey; position:absolute; left: 100px; top:0;"></div>

<div class="div" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:grey; position:absolute; left:500px; top:0;"></div>
```